# In dplyr using str_detect and case_when in R

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr

This is my df:

```
mydf <- structure(list(Action = c("Passes accurate", "Passes accurate", 
"Passes accurate", "Passes accurate", "Lost balls", "Lost balls (in opp. half)", 
"Passes (inaccurate)", "Interceptions (in opp. half)", "Interceptions", 
"Positional attacks")), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I have this vector: `passes <- c('Passes','passes','Assists','Crosses')`

I am trying to do this: `mydf %>% mutate(newcol = case_when(str_detect(Action, passes) ~ 'passes'))`

But I only have the frst row filled with `passes`. I should have for example the first 4 rows filled with `passes`. Also the 7th row. How can I achieve this with `case_when` function?

Comment: Change your mutate code to this: ```mutate(newcol = case_when(str_detect(Action, "Passes") ~ "passes")```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used `str_sub()` for this.

```
mydf %>% mutate(newcol = case_when(str_sub(Action,1,6) == 'Passes' ~ "passes"))

print(mydf)
   Action                       newcol
   <chr>                        <chr> 
 1 Passes accurate              passes
 2 Passes accurate              passes
 3 Passes accurate              passes
 4 Passes accurate              passes
 5 Lost balls                   NA    
 6 Lost balls (in opp. half)    NA    
 7 Passes (inaccurate)          passes
 8 Interceptions (in opp. half) NA    
 9 Interceptions                NA    
10 Positional attacks           NA
```

Answer (score 2):

You can easily do:

```
library(tidyverse)
mydf %>%
  mutate(newcol = if_else(str_detect(Action, paste0(passes, collapse = '|')), 'passes', NA_character_))

# A tibble: 10 x 2
   Action                       newcol
   <chr>                        <chr> 
 1 Passes accurate              passes
 2 Passes accurate              passes
 3 Passes accurate              passes
 4 Passes accurate              passes
 5 Lost balls                   <NA>  
 6 Lost balls (in opp. half)    <NA>  
 7 Passes (inaccurate)          passes
 8 Interceptions (in opp. half) <NA>  
 9 Interceptions                <NA>  
10 Positional attacks           <NA>
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use `paste(collapse = "|")` so that you can break the vector into one single string separated by "|", and then `grepl()` can look for element 1 or element 2 or element 3 and so on against "Action".

```
library(dplyr)

passes <- c('Passes','passes','Assists','Crosses')

mydf %>% mutate(newcol = case_when(grepl(paste(passes, collapse = "|"), Action) ~ "passes"))

# A tibble: 10 x 2
   Action                       newcol
   <chr>                        <chr> 
 1 Passes accurate              passes
 2 Passes accurate              passes
 3 Passes accurate              passes
 4 Passes accurate              passes
 5 Lost balls                   NA    
 6 Lost balls (in opp. half)    NA    
 7 Passes (inaccurate)          passes
 8 Interceptions (in opp. half) NA    
 9 Interceptions                NA    
10 Positional attacks           NA
```

Answer (score 1):

An option is also to use `fuzzyjoin`

```
library(fuzzyjoin)
library(dplyr)
regex_left_join(mydf, tibble(passes, newcol = "passes"),
    by = c("Action" = "passes")) %>%
   select(-passes)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 10 × 2
   Action                       newcol
   <chr>                        <chr> 
 1 Passes accurate              passes
 2 Passes accurate              passes
 3 Passes accurate              passes
 4 Passes accurate              passes
 5 Lost balls                   <NA>  
 6 Lost balls (in opp. half)    <NA>  
 7 Passes (inaccurate)          passes
 8 Interceptions (in opp. half) <NA>  
 9 Interceptions                <NA>  
10 Positional attacks           <NA>
```